# C++ how to check if a program is running for the first time?

Tags: c++, console-application

Using text files as a database. How do you get your program to know if it is running for the first time? If it is run for the first time, then the application needs to create the tables where the entities will be stored. If it is not run for the first time, then it should run the application with the user data if there is any data stored in the text files.

Comment: How about this, if the tables don't exist, it's running for the first time?

Comment: @Ecto Don't assume that. They can be deleted later. But then that's why you write your program not to care about the distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't.

You don't care whether the program is running for the first time.

You care whether the tables exist.

If they don't, create them.

That covers first launch and also any future "accidents".

Answer (score 1):

Check if the tables exist. If they don't, create them.